# What is the use of property-ref in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-property), under section `5.1.4.2. Property mapping with hbm.xml`, it is mentioned that :

> unique (optional): enables the DDL generation of a unique constraint for
>   the columns. Also, **allow this to be the target of a property-ref**.

What is the purpose of `porperty-ref` attribute in Hibernate and when we need to use this? please explain.

Answer (score 1):

When Associations on alternate keys that can be done by `property-ref` attribute.

`property-ref` (optional): the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.

Follow below links to understand by example in detail:

- [**Associations on alternate keys**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html)
- [**Collections of values and many-to-many associations**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html)